# How to perform client-server test without scripting?

Tags: testing, load, testcomplete, grinder

I have a clien-server application and I want to perform load test on it.
the problem is that I don't have for example 100 clients to start connecting to the server and test the app for me.
I have used some application like [Avalanche](http://www.spirent.com/Ethernet_Testing/Software/Avalanche) and [TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/) for this purpose, but unfortunately they just simulate `HTTP` and `HTTPs`tests and is usable for web application test not cilent-server test.
what I need is something like testComplete to be able to save the transactions and replay them hundreds of time or like avalanche.
also I have seen some other applications like [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) which has been suggested here before, but it's not possible for me to write script for performing test.
Does any body know any good application for this job or any way to write script for performing tests easily?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I have read all of the questions about this problem in SO. None of them contains what I need. then do not repeat them or link them here.

Comment: What do you want to test? Just load test on getting connection? If so, why you don't do that with a simple application which you'll gonna wrote?

Comment: @HBizhi not just for connecting, I want to test whether different functionalities can be performed at the same time from different clients or not. I mean at the same time different clinet can login, click on the same part, enter information access to the database and ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using TestComplete's [distributed testing](http://support.smartbear.com/articles/testcomplete/distributed-testing-tutorial). This way you can run GUI tests in parallel on multiple computers/virtual machines. The "clients" can be synchronized by using [synchronization points](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/58824/).

Note: You'll need a TestComplete or TestExecute license for each computer participating in a distributed test.